# Partition problems when dual booting with Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I got a laptop about two weeks ago. It was running Windows 10. It had a 1TB hard drive, and in Windows 10 the C: drive had 892 GB and the D: drive had 25GB. I decided to install Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit. In the installation wizard, when it detected Windows Boot Manager, I chose to boot alongside Windows. It showed me a 957GB partition, and I allocated 351 GB to Windows and 606GB to Ubuntu. The installation worked fine. Ubuntu was running smoothly for about a week and a half, after which I experienced some problems. I messed around with some things, and I eventually caused Ubuntu to become unusable. I booted into Windows and tried to delete Ubuntu and return my laptop to the state it was in pre-installation. I went to computer management and deleted the Ubuntu partitions, and the C: drive returned to 892GB. However, in the UEFI settings "ubuntu" still existed, and booting into it showed a weird GRUB BASH command line. On entering "exit" pressing enter I was given a menu that looked like the UEFI boot menu, where I was given a choice of booting into Windows Boot Manager, which I did. I tried installing Ubuntu again, but this time when I chose to boot alongside the Windows Boot Manager, it showed me a partition where 18.7GB was allocated to Ubuntu and about 8GB was allocated to something called "Files". I went back and chose "Something Else". I saw my 1TB hard drive, which had 957 GB, and chose ext2 and mounted "/". "Format drive" was selected. On clicking "Install now", a warning was given that there was no swap space. I decided against installation. My question is, is there anyway to bring back the first partition, where it was Windows against Ubuntu in the 957 GB hard drive?
Also, is there anyway to permanently remove the first Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 0):

There was a way to permanently delete Ubuntu Partition by clicking on 'something else' in Ubuntu installation option. Now you select 'Manual partition' see carefully all the partitions on your drive.
and then you will find the Ubuntu partition and then you format it by selecting the Ubuntu partition and then you will met some options then you click on 'format this volume'. Now you have deleted it permanently. If you want to install Ubuntu manually you need to create a swap area, which should be a size of your Ram (approximately).

If you get grub when you power-on your laptop, Then it is suggested that you don't delete Ubuntu rather install on the existing one itself.

I hope this was helpful.